docker-compose golang cannot access php service
I have a docker-compose file with nginx, golang and php services.
When trying to access the php services from golang service, I get an error "Get \"http://accounting:9000/\": read tcp 172.22.0.5:43016->172.22.0.2:9000: read: connection reset by peer"
I also, want the php service to be accessed only internally, so, it should not be exposed to the outside.
docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  apigateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/go/apigateway/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
      - internal-network
    volumes:
      - ./apigateway:/apigateway
  accounting:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal-network
    volumes:
      - ./accounting:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - apigateway
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.26.0
    ports:
      - "8780:80"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - apigateway
    networks:
      - app-network
      - internal-network

networks:
  app-network:
  internal-network:
    internal: true


.docker/php/Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config libzip-dev

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./accounting .

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]


And here is the code I'm using to test the access from golang:
    router.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
        url := "http://accounting:9000/"

        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
                fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)

    })

I tried changing the port for php-fpm and I also played with different php -fpm images including alpine but without any success

PHP-FPM uses the FastCGI protocol. I'm not sure accessing it over http is intended to work

As commented by @apokryfos, PHP-FPM uses the FastCGI protocol. This means it needs a server to translate the request from the http to the FactCGI protocol.
To solve the problem, I just used a different php image bundled with an apache server FROM php:8.3-apache
